# How to validate inputs from a list in Java

Tags: java, validation

So I am currently trying to write a student results project with a validator that will only allow the specific inputs (0,20,40,60,80,100,120). I am guessing that the 'white list' will need to be a list but I have no idea how to do this and I have spent hours trying to find out.

So far my code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    int pass, defer, fail;


    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // read in the marks for each pass, defer or fail
    System.out.println("Enter the pass credits: "); 
    pass = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the defer credits:"); 
    defer = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter the fail credits:");
    fail = in.nextInt();

        //Coditions for each input
        if(pass == 120){
            System.out.println("Progress");
        }
        else if(fail <= 80) {
            System.out.println("Exclude");
        }
        else if(pass == 100 && defer == 20 || fail == 20 && pass == 100){
            System.out.println("Progress - Module Trailer");
        }

        else {
            System.out.println("Do not progress - module retreiver");
        }

}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: So you want to get input from user and then process only those which are part of whitelisted numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try creating a `set` of valid inputs and create a simple validator function:

```
private static final Set<Integer> numbers = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{0,20,40,60,80,100,120}));

static boolean isValidInput(int num){
    return numbers.contains(num);
}
```

Using a `set` is appropriately justified in your case because later on, you might wish to include more numbers and search through them in which case, you would want a Data Structure that would return if the number is present in a pre-defined list of numbers with `O(1)` complexity.

Use this method to check if your input is valid and handle the false cases appropriately.